# Upgrade typo3 7.6.32 on Virtual Machine, website broken After changing Symlink, and any idea how to update typo3 7 to 10

Tags: php, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

How to change `symlink` and update to version 10 in the right way ?

I made backup for DB and the whole typo3 file, then I upgraded wizard. Everything was good, but when I set up symlink manually, everything broke.
So back to update file, got an error code 500 on backend and frontend.
Anyone has idea how to do update from 7 to 10 and how to change symlink properly.

Comment: would you consider using composer? It is waaaaaaay easier to update a TYPO3 instance and you will not have such problems

Comment: Thanks for your reply, no i didn't, first i want to do it on virtual machine then and if everything okay i will do it on live server
 can i use composer on virtual machine ?
and do you know any docomunation or tutorial how can i update or upgrade typo3 7 to version 10 

Thanks

Comment: as far as i understand, you download the source code via ZIP etc. If you want to update to the newest TYPO3 version, you download again the zip file and you are trying to rebuild the symlinks to the new version right? If yes, with composer you avoid all the hasle and with one command, you can update your TYPO3 instance without having to worry about anything. Here is a guide, although i am not sure you want to use ddev. https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/QuickInstall/Composer/Index.html . Can you please share your Folder structure?